# Задача по БД Northwind

Tags: sql, sql-server

Показать 1 первый и 1 последний заказ (номер заказа и дату заказа) каждого продавца (достаточно вывести EmployeeID) без использования `GROUP BY` и `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, OrderDate,
       FIRST_VALUE(OrderID) OVER (
       PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
       ORDER BY OrderDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
AND CURRENT ROW) AS first_order, 
       LAST_VALUE(OrderID) OVER (
       PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
       ORDER BY OrderDate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_order
FROM Orders
```

А как реализовать запрос не для 1-го первого и последнего заказа, а например для 2-х заказов?

Знаю, как отдельно вывести 2 первых заказа через ROW_NUMBER, но как к ним добавить еще и 2 последних?

```
WITH LastDate
AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID, OrderDate, OrderID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
       ORDER BY OrderDate 
       ) AS FD
FROM Orders
)

SELECT EmployeeID, OrderDate, OrderID
FROM LastDate
WHERE FD < 3
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и отбор во внешнем запросе по фиксированным номерам.

Comment: можно банально добавить второй `row_number() over (.. order by OrderDate DESC) as ld`  и `OR ld < 3`

Comment: за что минуса-то? хороший учебный вопрос, имхо.

Comment: @teran балин... Я вчера все это решил, но написать OR вместо AND у меня мозгов не хватило... Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH LastDate
AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID, OrderDate, OrderID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
       ORDER BY OrderDate 
       ) AS FD, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
       ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
       ) AS LD
FROM Orders
)

SELECT EmployeeID, OrderDate, OrderID
FROM LastDate
WHERE FD < 3  or LD < 3
```